# JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT: everytime i click this check box i get JS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onchange

I have this checkbox when clicked suppose to toggle(check or un-check) all other checkboxes of class "boxes" BUT instead gives this error:

```
Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" name="cb" value="some_val" onchange="dosomething()" />

<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" name="boxes[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" name="boxes[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" name="boxes[]" value="3" />
```

Here is the JS/JQUERY:

```
function dosomething(){
   $('.boxes:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked")); 
}
```

I don't understand what that JQUERY error is.

Comment: what does dosomething() do?

Comment: You have to provide full information about dosomething() function.

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function with inline `onchange`, the context isn't set, so you can't use `$(this)` in the function. You need to pass the element explicitly.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" name="cb" value="some_val" onchange="dosomething(this)" />

function doSomething(el) {
    $('.boxes:checkbox').prop('checked', $(el).is(":checked"));
}
```

Or you could do the event binding in jQuery:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" name="cb" value="some_val" id="checkAll" />

$("#checkAll").click(function() {
    $('.boxes:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: tyvm.  And i just like to say both php/javascript are bad languages.  Ty for help again.